# Winforms ListView ItemCheck on load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, events

I have a winform containing tabs, containing a usercontrol, containing a listview with checkboxes.

```
    private void lvwRoles_ItemCheck(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!m_loading && m_locked)
        {
            e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
            return;
        }
```

The listview is assigned it's items (some is checked) in a method (in the user control) that is called from the parent form. This is done on load of the parent form.

My problem is that the `ItemCheck` occurs when I click the corresponding tab the first time.
That results in the `m_loading` state variable being false since long ago.
Thus no item is ever checked when the usercontrol is `m_locked`.

Is there a way to solve this without changing how the listview is populated?

Comment: Pretty unclear.  Use the debugger, set a breakpoint on this method.  The call stack shows you why the event got fired.

Comment: @HansPassant Of course I have tried that. It showed [Non user code], Main, [Non user code], ItemCheck. The event is obviously deferred by the framework until the gui is loaded. My question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The listview is assigned it's items (some is checked) in a method (in
>   the user control) that is called from the parent form. This is done on
>   load of the parent form.

Even though you call that method in the parent form_load that effectively fires when you select that tab. Set `m_loading` to false after user control loads, which will not occur until you select that tab.